# How to select all columns from multiple SQLite databases

Tags: database, sqlite

I am doing queries over multiple databases in **SQLite**, and I'm having trouble using a .* in my queries. I have successfully used the ATTACH function to reference both databases:

```
dbOne.execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'dbOne.sql' as db1");
dbOne.execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'dbTwo.sql' as db2");
```

This query here gives me a syntax error (syntax error near *):

```
dbOne.execute("SELECT db2.myTable.* FROM db2.myTable");
```

Can I do `db2.myTable.*`? Or do I have to select each individual column one at a time?

```
SELECT db2.myTable.columnA, db2.myTable.columnB, db2.myTable.columnC, etc.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you have not solved this already, this will work:

a) `dbOne.execute("SELECT * FROM db2.myTable");`

b) `dbOne.execute("SELECT abc.* FROM db2.myTable abc");`

Also, you don't have to specify the database name when the tablename is unique across all attached databases.

b) is commonly used when you select or join multiple tables, e.g.

`SELECT abc.*, xyz.* FROM db2.myTable abc, db1.myOtherTable xyz`